# MVC remove dropdown list on edits

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, edit

I created a website by using the automatic scaffolding tool in VS2015.
On the edit.cshtml page, 2 fields that come from related tables (primary keys in each) are showing up as dropdown lists.  I only want to display the value of those fields from each related table, not a dropdown list, as those values should not editable.

In the controller, I eliminated the ViewBag.(field).  In the view, I changed the fields to @Html.DisplayFor(...) instead of @Html.DropDownList(...).  Now the page displays correctly, but when I save the edits, I get the following error:
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint...

Instrument Model:

```
    public partial class equipment
    {
(...) 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int tmde_id { get; set; }
        public int acct_id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        public string instrument_id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("S/N")]
        public string serial_nbr { get; set; }
        public string dept { get; set; }
(...)
        public virtual account account { get; set; }
        public virtual tmde tmde { get; set; }
(...)
```

Controller:

```
        // GET: Instruments/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            equipment equipment = db.equipment.Find(id);
            if (equipment == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            ViewBag.acct_id = new SelectList(db.account, "id", "acct_nbr", equipment.acct_id);
            ViewBag.tmde_id = new SelectList(db.tmde, "id", "noun", equipment.tmde_id);
            return View(equipment);
        }

        // POST: Instruments/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = 

"id,tmde_id,acct_id,instrument_id,serial_nbr,dept,location,on_site,cal_cycle,cal_interval,edit_user,edit_date,active,cal_due,short_note")] equipment equipment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(equipment).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.acct_id = new SelectList(db.account, "id", "acct_nbr", equipment.acct_id);
            ViewBag.tmde_id = new SelectList(db.tmde, "id", "noun", equipment.tmde_id);
            return View(equipment);
        }
```

View for Edit page:

```
(...)
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.instrument_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.instrument_id, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.instrument_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.account.name)
        @Html.DropDownList("acct_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tmde.noun)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tmde.noun)
        @Html.DropDownList("tmde_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tmde.mfr)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tmde.mfr)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tmde.model)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tmde.model)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.serial_nbr)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.serial_nbr)
        <br />
```

Comment: can you post the view and controller code?

Comment: The description is about MVC but the error looks like a SQL problem, can you put here the minimum code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Silly question... I'm new to StackOverflow.  I'd like to post my code, but it's too long to add as a comment.  Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Model for Instruments:

    public partial class equipment
    {
(...) 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int tmde_id { get; set; }
        public int acct_id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        public string instrument_id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("S/N")]
        public string serial_nbr { get; set; }
        public string dept { get; set; }
(...)
        public virtual account account { get; set; }
        public virtual tmde tmde { get; set; }
(...)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do this!  The model was fine.  Here are the changes I made:

**Controller**:
**Replaced**

```
ViewBag.acct_id = new SelectList(db.account, "id", "acct_nbr", equipment.acct_id);
ViewBag.tmde_id = new SelectList(db.tmde, "id", "noun", equipment.tmde_id);
return View(equipment);
```

**With**

```
ViewBag.acct_id = equipment.acct_id;
ViewBag.tmde_id = equipment.tmde_id;
return View(equipment);
```

**Edit.cshtml**:
Added to the top of the page

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.tmde_id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.acct_id)
```

In the body where I display the various fields:

```
<dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.tmde.noun)</dt>
<dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tmde.noun)</dd>
```

I can display any field from the equipment table as well as the related tables.

This code ensures that the foreign keys are maintained (hidden because they aren't editable by user) while still allowing the other fields from the equipment table to be edited.  Now the database UPDATE works perfectly.

Hope this will help someone else that may encounter the same situation.